# Calculate the probability density function of an independent random vector

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

Let $X \sim \operatorname{Exp}(\lambda)$ and $Y \sim \operatorname{Exp}(\mu)$ be independent. Consider the random vector $Z = (X,Y)$.

How can I now calculate the probability density function $f_Z$?

Since $Z$ is independent its probability density function must be the product of the corresponding marginal density functions. How can I proceed from here?

Edit: Not a duplicate since my question resolves around a random vector.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Joint density for exponential distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2972227/joint-density-for-exponential-distribution)

Comment: The question is about the random vector, not a duplicate of the linked target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the density of $Z$ is the product of the marginals, so the three densities are as follows:
\begin{align*}
&f_X(x) =
\lambda \exp(-\lambda x),
\\
&f_Y(y) =
\mu \exp(-\mu y),
\\
&f_Z(x,y) = f_X(x)f_Y(y) =
\lambda\mu \exp(-\lambda x-\mu y).
\end{align*}
Note, that $f_X$ and $f_Y$ are defined only on $\mathbb R_{\ge 0}$ (you may define them to be zero for negative $x,y$, if you want densities on all of $\mathbb R$) and that $f_Z$ is a density on $\mathbb R_{\ge 0}^2$ (so depending on two variables).